# Edittext form validation

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I have a form where I've put a validation like this

```
if( firstName.getText().toString().length() < 3 )
    firstName.setError( "First name is required!" );
```

So if the inputted text is **smaller than 3 characters** I get an error with the text **"First name is required!"** and I also get a red icon in the editText. 
But I'd like to have an `else`for when the inputted data is correct so I'll get a green icon in the editText. What property can I use for that?

**EDIT:** Is it also possible to do a check while typing and not after pressing a button?

Comment: u said smaller means == ????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.youGreenDrawable, 0, 0, 0);
```

You have to use [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: Android doesn't have build in for this action?

Comment: If the data in my EditText is valide, doesn't android have a build in property for the valid part with it's own icon, without me making one? Like for the invalid part android provides a buildin red icon when I use `EditText.setError`

Comment: Okay, I'll wait a few more hours to get more answer to be certain. If nothing shows up I'll create icons and do it your way!